# How can I extract a word (string) and a couple of words inside a R observation?

Tags: r, string, extract

This is my df:

```
Phrase               
  <chr>                 
1 I am hungry               
2 I am going to school     
3 It's raining              
4 I like talking
```

I would like to extract some key words like ("Hungry", "School", "I" and "I am") for each observation, like this:

```
  Phrase               Hungry School     I `I am`
  <chr>                 <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 I am hungry               1      0     1      1
2 I am going to school      0      1     1      1
3 It's raining              0      0     0      0
4 I like talking            0      0     1      0
```

In the example above, it could have the number 1 if the column name is inside the phrase, and 0 it it doesn't (or could be another kind of extraction).

I tried reading some articles like this one: https://www.r-bloggers.com/an-overview-of-keyword-extraction-techniques/, but I haven't find any information to help me extract these key words.

Comment: `I` and `I am` are intersecting

Answer (score 3):

We can loop over the vector of words with `sapply`, apply `grepl` to get a logical vector, and convert to binary with `+`

```
v1 <- c("Hungry", "School", "I", "I am")
cbind(df1, +(sapply(v1, function(v) grepl(paste0("\\b", toupper(v), 
       "\\b"), toupper(df1$Phrase)))))
#               Phrase Hungry School I I am
#1          I am hungry      1      0 1    1
#2 I am going to school      0      1 1    1
#3         It's raining      0      0 0    0
#4       I like talking      0      0 1    0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Phrase = c("I am hungry", "I am going to school", 
"It's raining", "I like talking")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"))
```

Answer (score 2):

you could use `grepl` on each word, but careful attention needs to be taken as you could have false positives.

```
Phrase <- c("I am hungry","I am going to school","It's raining ","I like talking")

data.frame(phrase=Phrase,
    hungry = grepl("hungry",tolower(Phrase))*1,
    school = grepl("school",tolower(Phrase))*1,
    i = grepl("i\\s|\\si",tolower(Phrase))*1,
    iam = grepl("i am",tolower(Phrase))*1)

                phrase hungry scholl i iam
1          I am hungry      1      0 1   1
2 I am going to school      0      1 1   1
3        It's raining       0      0 0   0
4       I like talking      0      0 1   0
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution:

```
search_words <- c("Hungry", "School", "I", "I am")
cbind(df1, data.frame(+(Vectorize(grepl)(search_words, df1, ignore.case = TRUE))))
```

Data: @akrun thank you.

```
df1 <- structure(list(Phrase = c("I am hungry", "I am going to school", 
"It's raining", "I like talking")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"))
```